# views generated pager url

Tags: views, uri, paging

How can I get the url generated by the pager in views.

drupal/project11?page=1
drupal/project11?page=2

I would like to add a link on my image to the 2nd page on my first image, to the 3th page on my 2nd image without using the pager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking for a link to a View like `drupal/project11/1` or `drupal/project11/2`. You can do this with [Clean Pagination](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleanpager) module.

> Clean Pagination is a very simple module that allows you to enable
>   clean URL pagination for specified pages. The way Drupal typically
>   works, if you had a view with the URL 'my-view', subsequent pages
>   would normally use a query to pass the page number, as in
>   'my-view?page=2'. When Clean Pagination is being used for a page, it
>   will create a url like 'my-view/2'.
>
> Currently, the module has just two settings: 1) Set the pages where
>   you want clean pagination enabled, and 2) Enable
>   search-engine-friendly pagination hyperlinks.
>
> The search-engine-friendly pagination hyperlinks is an experimental
>   feature you can optionally turn on that will add the page URL to
>   pagination links, and then remove them via jQuery. To a user, it will
>   look like a single number, but to a screen readers and search engines
>   it will have the url in the hyperlink text, which is usually a good
>   thing.